# Sum numbers that contain a letter in the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to sum a3:b21 but in these cells they will either have a c or s as the first character in the cell, Some cells might just be the letter itself. the values can be in the range of $1 all the up to $99999.

I have tried a few different formulas but none are adding the cells. Some of the formulas I have tried are

```
=SUM(IF((LEFT(A3:B20,1))=C3,(--RIGHT((IF(A3:B20="",0,A3:B20)),7)),0))

=IF(ISNUMBER(A3:B20),M3,VALUE(RIGHT(M3,SEARCH(" ",A3:B20)-1)))

=SUMIF(A3:B20,M2,A3:B20)

=SUMIF(A3:B19, "s*")
```

For the time being while I try and figure out a formula that works I have m2 for the letter s and m3 for the letter c, for testing different formulas.

Sample cell:

[image: sample cell]

Comment: Why not use an array formula such as `=SUM(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A4:A15,"c","")))`? That worked for me on the downloaded file.

Comment: When I tried using the formula you posted it wasnt working for me and it was only showing the value of cell 13.

Comment: @diabetesman the formula above is an array formula.  After pasting the formula in the formula bar hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  If done correctly excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Or you can use SUMPRODUCT() instead `=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A4:A21,"c","")))`

Comment: Thanks for the help I was getting a #value! error buts because i was doing a3 in the value and that cell was causing an error. By any chance is there a way to set the formula to substitute c or s for the column? I tried modifying it a few different ways but I kept getting different errors.

Comment: Some pro tips for posting: please don't use Dropbox and other file lockers - if a question cannot be fully expressed in a self-contained way, then it is off-topic. This is because in our experience, external links die off fairly quickly, which means then it is not so useful for future readers. Also, please don't add [solved] to titles - to mark a question as such please click the tick mark next to the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a column and sum from that try this, it acts like a replace() function.  Will remove c and s.  You can nest other substitutes() to remove other characters as necessary

```
=substitute(substitute("a3","c",""),"s","")+0
```

Then copy for other cells

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT(A1:A3,1)="c"),IFERROR(--RIGHT(A1:A3,LEN(A1:A3)-1),0))
```

CSE-entered.